# How do I override the root key in a Grape API response payload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api, grape-entity

```rb
module Entities
  class StuffEntity < Grape::Entity
    root 'stuffs', 'stuff'
    ...
```

How can I DRY up my code by reusing this entity while still having the flexibility to rename the root keys ('stuffs' and 'stuff') defined in the entity?

I might need to do this in a scenario where I'm exposing a subset of a collection represented by an existing entity or exposing an associated collection that can be represented by an existing entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hiding the root key when you're exposing an associated object or collection

Let's say I have an object with a `name` attribute and some collection of `scoped_stuff` that I want to expose as `some_stuffs`. I could do that with an entity like this:

```rb
module Entities
  class CoolStuffEntity < Grape::Entity
    root 'cool_stuffs', 'cool_stuff'
    
    expose :some_stuffs, documentation: {
      type: Entities::StuffEntity
    } do |object, _options|
      Entities::StuffEntity.represent(
        object.class.scoped_stuff,
        root: false
      )
    end
    
    expose :name, documentation: { type: 'string' }
  end
end
```

Passing `root: false` to the `represent` method ensures that the nested association is represented without a root key. Here are what the representations look like with and without that argument:

```
# Without root: false
cool_stuff: {
  some_stuffs: { 
    stuffs:    [ /* collection represented by StuffEntity */ ] 
  },
  name: 'Something'
}

# With root: false
cool_stuff: { 
  some_stuffs: [ /* collection represented by StuffEntity */ ],
  name:        'Something'
}
```

In this instance, passing `root: false` ensures that the nested entity's root key isn't included in our representation.

### Setting a root key name when presenting an entity with no defined root

Let's say we have this entity where we did not specify root:

```rb
module Entities
  class StuffEntity < Grape::Entity
    expose :name, documentation: { type: 'string' }
  end
end
```

The serializable hash for an object represented with this entity will look like: `{ name: 'Object name' }`

In our API, we can specify the response key like so:

```rb
get do
  stuff_object = Stuff.find_by(user_id: current_user)

  present stuff_object, 
    with: Entities::StuffEntity,
    root: :stuff
end
```

So that our response will look like this: `{ stuff: { name: 'Object name' } }`

*Note that 'root' accepts string and symbol arguments here.*

### If you want to rename the root key in your API response

So what if I have an entity where I specified a root key *and* I want the key in my response to be different (e.g., exposing a subset of the collection)? Instead of using `present`, I can use `represent` again. Except this time, instead of disabling the root key by passing 'false', I can give it a key name:

```rb
get do
  my_stuff = Stuff.find_by(user_id: current_user)

  Entities::StuffEntity.represent(
    my_stuff,
    root: :my_stuff
  )
end
```